# STOMP heart beat tracking using java and activemq-all library

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, messaging, stomp

I am consuming a message feed using the below code from a third party message broker. We use the [STOMP](https://stomp.github.io) protocol and the code is developed using the [activemq-all](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.activemq/activemq-all/5.15.8) library. I have noticed that the connection is hanging occasionally (after every 1-2 weeks without any feed). So I wanted to use the heart-beat feature of STOMP protocol so I have added the [heart-beat](https://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.2.html#Heart-beating) header for the `stompConnection` as shown below:

```
StompConnection stompConnection = new StompConnection();
stompConnection.open(new Socket("ABC", 1234));
HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
headers.put("login", "abcd");
headers.put("passcode", "defghij");
headers.put("heart-beat", "0,10000");//heart-beat header newly added
stompConnection.connect(headers);
stompConnection.subscribe("topic1", "auto");
while(true) {
    StompFrame stompMessage = stompConnection.receive(10000);
    String messageBody = stompMessage.getBody();
    //process messageBody here
}
```

Now my question is that is there any way to find/trace that my application (above java client) is receiving the heart beats from the sender?

Answer (score 1):

That library is a test support only tool with no support for issues other than those affecting ActiveMQ tests.  Using it is risky and not recommended for any production level work.  You'd be far better off using a full open source Stomp client with actual support.  The track heart beats with this client you would need to drop to the socket level and track the incoming bytes directly.

Comment: Thanks, so we can't track heart beats through a program? Also, can you give few examples/suggestions for the libraries on the "full open source Stomp client with actual support"?

Comment: I have contacted my friend(google) before SO and had a look at your link long back, basically looking for alternatives for ActiveMQ and gozirra libraries.